# Simplifying JQuery web api calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build a very simple API.

Here's the controller:

```
public class SearchOptions
{
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
}

public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Test(SearchOptions options)
    {
        return options.SearchText;
    }
}
```

This works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/api/test",
    data: "{'searchText':'xxxx'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) { $("#GetData").text(result); },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Now I'd like to (a) use the shorthand $.post() and (b) use the $(form).serialize() to produce the data literal.

So I try this:

```
var data = $("#searchForm").serialize();

$.post(
    "/api/test", 
    data, 
    function(result) { $("#GetData").text(result); }, 
    "json"
);
```

That doesn't work. If I check the value of data, it's `"searchText=xxxx"`. So maybe that's the issue. I try this:

```
$.post(
    "/api/test", 
    "{'searchText':'xxxx'}", 
    function(result) { $("#GetData").text(result); }, 
    "json"
);
```

Still doesn't work. What's missing/wrong?

EDIT--------------

So $.post() uses `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and MVC API Controller can't  map the form parameters to a complex object if that is being used, according to http://forums.asp.net/t/1922381.aspx

I watched Scott Allen's MVC 5 video and he seems to use $.post() to the built-in account controller (eg: registering). I don't have access to the account controller (VS2013) to see how it maps the form parameters to a complex object.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the double-quotes from data. i.e. put like - {'searchText':'xxxx'}